# Accessing Session variable in action class

Tags: java, struts2

i have struts2.0 in my project, i am storing username in session by implements SessionAware  done as follows

```
public class NewProduct extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware{
 private Map session;
 public String execute() {
 session.put("username", "Rangappa");
 return "success"
}

public void setSession(Map session) {
    this.session = session;

}
public Map getSession() {
    return session;
  }
```

here I am setting session variable here, i m not getting how to get this session variable in other class,
 i done as below  but its not working

```
public class NewProduct extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware{
 public String execute() throws Exception {
 String username = (String) session.get("username");
 System.out.println("username: "+username );
  return "success"
 }
}
```

both class are in same packages, please let me know solution, Thanks i advance

Comment: what problem are you facing while getting it?

Comment: Are they two different classes? (Both are named `NewProduct`...)

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi seems you are right, i am not familiar with `SessionAware` interface, it should be flexible, my answer is pointless, i will remove it right now

Comment: @Umesh Awasthi,when i access session varaible its give nullpoint error

Comment: servletConfig interceptor is designed to set all properties an action needs if it's aware of servlet parameters, the servlet context, the session, etc. Post your action configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code after importing the appropriate packages

```
Map session = ActionContext.getContext().get("session");
String userName = (String)(session.get("username"));
```

Comment: The `SessionAware` is preferably way to get session. And there is `getSession()` method in `ActionContext`.